# PHP Add arrays to another array without key

Tags: php, arrays

I need to create the following array:

```
$data = array(
   "invoice_info" => array(
       ...
    ),
    "product_info => array(
        array(
           "name" => "product 1",
           ...
        ),
        array(
           "name => "product 2",
            ...
        )
    )
);
```

I am currently struggling to get the products into my "product_info" array. For each product I want to add I use the following line:

```
$product_info[] = array("name" => "product 1", ...);
```

This works fine for the first one. Adding another one, however, overwrites it. The second problem is, that keys are added, that should not be there:

```
[product_info] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => product 2
                [qty] => 293
                [price] => 44
                [sum] => 12892
            )

    )
```

This is the output after adding 2 products. Just the second one is included. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The value  "name" is the a key  (always the same key ) so without a proper index  you can't append the same array  .. each time you add  name=> array your overwrite the previous

Comment: Where does `$product_info` come from? It's `$data['product_info']`.

Comment: Please show your actual code, it's impossible to tell what you're doing wrong from that one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will generate you an array of arrays

```
$data = array(
    "invoice_info" => array(),
    "product_info" => array(),
    );

$data['product_info'][] = ['name' => 'prod1','qty'=>1, 'price'=> 44, 'sum'=>100];
$data['product_info'][] = ['name' => 'prod2','qty'=>22, 'price'=> 55, 'sum'=>200];

print_r($data);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [invoice_info] => Array
        (
        )

    [product_info] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => prod1
                    [qty] => 1
                    [price] => 44
                    [sum] => 100
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => prod2
                    [qty] => 22
                    [price] => 55
                    [sum] => 200
                )

        )

)
```

Now if you had done something like this

```
$product_info =& $data['product_info'];
```

to create your `$product_info` variable then note that you must use the `=&` or when you attempt to allocate a new array it will not work as you expect. So, adding that to the previous code would look like this

```
$data = array(
    "invoice_info" => array(),
    "product_info" => array(),
    );

$data['product_info'][] = ['name' => 'prod1','qty'=>1, 'price'=> 44, 'sum'=>100];
$data['product_info'][] = ['name' => 'prod2','qty'=>22, 'price'=> 55, 'sum'=>200];


$product_info =& $data['product_info'];

$product_info[] = ['name' => 'prod3','qty'=>99, 'price'=> 155, 'sum'=>300];

print_r($data);
```

Will produce the result

```
Array
(
    [invoice_info] => Array
        (
        )
    [product_info] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => prod1
                    [qty] => 1
                    [price] => 44
                    [sum] => 100
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => prod2
                    [qty] => 22
                    [price] => 55
                    [sum] => 200
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => prod3
                    [qty] => 99
                    [price] => 155
                    [sum] => 300
                )
        )
)
```